# Speech Recognition codes only give a few words for my 2-min wav file

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am running the following code to convert a 2-min speech. However, it only returns a few words and the "Process finished with exit code 0" is not seen. Same thing happens with a longer file, as well. What do you think the problem might be here? Thanks!

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def main():

    sound = "XYZ.wav"
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.AudioFile(sound) as source :
         r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

         print("Çalışıyor...")

         audio = r.listen(source)
         try:
             print("Dönüştürülen ses : \n " +r.recognize_google(audio, language = "tr-TR"))

         except Exception as e:
             print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: what's the expected output? Do other files work besides just this one? Is there a stacktrace?

Comment: my record contains lots of sentences, but the output is only a few words. I tried 2 files, same thing happened. I don't exactly know stacktrace, but I think there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the file has wrong format, extension doesn't mean anything. You can check format first:

```
file XYZ.wav
```

It should say something like this

```
 RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 8000 Hz
```

if not, you need to convert file to pcm.